# Search and Discovery of Teams Meetings

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a user friendly way to search for Teams meeting videos on Sharepoint?

When you used to record meetings on teams, they were available on streams.microsoft.com with search. This turned out to have a max capacity so we had to switch to keeping those videos on Sharepoint. Since then people have had a lot of trouble finding the videos they are after as they need to scroll through teams chats to get access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Simon Hilton:

Are you saying you reached your capacity of MS Stream under your current license?  If so, know this:  Stream will be deprecated later this year in favor of SharePoint-based video storage - Also (confusingly) branded as Stream - again - it will be hosted in Sharepoint.  I’m sure MSFT will have a migration path.  But that doesn’t fix your current issue.

Create a new Teams SharePoint site in your tenant (not connected to a group) using the STS#3 template using PowerShell:
Connect to SharePoint online using the PnP PowerShell:

```
cls
Write-Host “  “;
    Write-Host “Choose ‘Yes To-All’, when prompted” -BackgroundColor “Yellow” -ForegroundColor “Black”;
    Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -warningAction silentlyContinue;  
    Import-Module PnP.PowerShell -warningAction silentlyContinue;
    Write-Host “  “;
    Connect-PnP -URL https://**TenantBaseName**-admin.SharePoint.com -Interactive
    Write-Host “  “;
    New-PnPSite -Type TeamSiteWithoutMicrosoft365Group -URL “https://***your-tenant-name***.SharePoint.com/sites/***NewSite***/“  -Owner ***you@your-employer.com*** -StorageQuota 5000 -ResourceQuota 500 -Template STS#3 -Title ***Video Site Name*** -Description ***Description of the Site*** -ShareByEmailEnabled $true;
```

The items surrounded by two stars "**" e.g.: **word** or by three stars "***" e.g.: ***your-tenant-name*** you need to change those values *prior* to execution the script below:

2. Move all existing Stream hosted videos to your newly created site.
3. Use this

Add all your additional videos to a dedicated SharePoint site in the interim, located  You will then be able to manage them like regular SharePoint Objects if you are a Global Admin or a SharePoint Admin or even just a Site Collection Admin,
See these two articles: